# Laravel Sanctum for API auth on different domain

Tags: reactjs, laravel, api, axios, laravel-sanctum

I was authenticating API requests in Laravel and It was working on local perfectly but When I deployed both (React on Firebase, Laravel on different domain), API authentication stopped working.

This is `app/Http/Kernel.php`

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'api' => [
        \Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors::class,
        // \Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,
        'throttle:api',
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    ],
];
```

This is `config/cors.php`

```
    'paths' => ['api/*', 'sanctum/csrf-cookie'],

    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins' => ['http://localhost:3000', 'https://example.web.app'],

    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],

    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

    'exposed_headers' => [],

    'max_age' => 0,

    'supports_credentials' => true,
```

I'm getting 401 error when I make request from React with axios.

I asked from ChatGPT and searched alot but It didn't worked.

I want to make request and authenticate them with sanctum from different domain to Laravel.

///////////////// UPDATE ///////////////////

I switched to JWT auth because as @jurandou mentioned that `laravel/sanctum` does not support API authorization from different domain.

Comment: it's different domains or different subdomains ?

Comment: @jurandou different domains. eg: foo.web.app for react and bar.com for Laravel

Comment: AFAIK, Sanctum does not allow you to make cross domain requests. Only from subdomains from the same domain. You will have to use another package, like Passport to achieve that. Or use the tokens to authenticate your third party apps

Comment: Why are you think it's cros issue? As I know, it won't be http code 401 if laravel not allow the cros request.

Comment: Can you confirm the password/token is correct? Did you make DB seed after deployed?

Comment: @Charlie I know that It's not CORS issue but I faced the CORS problem. and password/token is correct. I made DB seed after deploying

Comment: @jurandou Laravel Passport is too complex, could you suggest any other lightweight and simple package for API auth

Comment: @GursahbWebcyst You can use the [API Token Authentication from Sanctum package](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/sanctum#api-token-authentication) instead of the SPA Authentication

Comment: Since your issue is not about Sanctum, for the cros issue, you just need to add `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` to **response header**.

Comment: And I just want to remind, there is a big hint on Laravel document. **"You should not use API tokens to authenticate your own first-party SPA. Instead, use Sanctum's built-in SPA authentication features."**

Comment: I switched to jwt token and I'm passing token with authorization header, but in laravel it won't get any token

Comment: @Charlie My issue is not about CORS, I'm able to make request without any problem.

Comment: @GursahbWebcyst Santum Api Token Auth is similar to JWT. Hitting the Route::post('tokens/create') you can generate a token with Sanctum, and then apply it in your requests. Don't forget to give it a short expiration, and renew it when needed

Comment: @jurandou Sorry if I didn't make it clear but I'm getting an error in Sanctum API Token Auth, It returns 401 unauthorised even though my token is not expired or wrong and I'm passing it with header `Authorization: \`Bearer ${token}\` ` correctly.

Comment: @GursahbWebcyst Sorry, my bad. I will post a more complete answer for exemple

Comment: Well... I figured out I misunderstood your issue, but because you solved, so I guess it's not matter. :(

Comment: @Charlie I just switched the authentication method, But I would like to know what you've figured out. It still matters. :)

Comment: @GursahbWebcyst No. I'm not figured out anything useful, it's just that I finally understood your question, feel sorry about not completely understood what you are asking, it might be misleading.

Comment: Because of Sanctum use default web guard, the default web guard is based on a session, so yes, it not supported different domain.

Answer (score 0):

On the domain with the API routes side, you will have to:

***Migrate, making sure there is the personal_access_tokens and users table***

***Create a user to have ability to create tokens on him***

***Edit the config/cors.php :***

```
'paths' => [
    'api/*', 
    'sanctum/csrf-cookie',
    'http://www.domain-to-accept-requests/*',
],

'supports_credentials' => true
```

***Create those routes in routes/api.php :*** (for exemple purpose)

```
Route::get('tokens/create', [ApiController::class, 'createTokens'])->name('tokens.create');

Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->get('/users/{user}', function (Request $request) {
    $user = User::find($request->user);
    return response($user);
});
```

***Create the ApiController with the method createTokens***

```
public function createTokens()
    {
        $user = User::find(1);
        
        $token_name = 'get_api_infos_token';

        $user->tokens()->where('name', $token_name)->delete();

        $token = $user->createToken($token_name, ['infos:get']);
 
        return ['token' => $token->plainTextToken];
    }
```

The 2nd parameter of the createToken method is useful if you want to check abilities, you can [refer to the sanctum doc](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/sanctum#token-ability-middleware) if interested.

On the other domain http://www.domain-to-accept-requests/, here is an exemple axios js

```
const testApi = async () => {
        try {
            const responseToken = await axios.get('http://www.api-domain.test/api/tokens/create')
            const headers = { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + responseToken.data.token }
            
            const response = await axios.get('http://www.api-domain.test/api/users/1', {headers})
            console.log(response.data)
        } catch (error) {}
    }
```

Hope it helps ?